# Uninstalled a program but its context menu is not disappear

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-10

I just uninstalled Tabby terminal. However, the context menu "Open Tabby here" does not disappear with it. I've tried deleting it via Registry Editor, in here:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell
```

and restarting the computer, but the context menu is still there. What do I have to do?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJaUm.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote that you tried something in the register, but not exactly what. Have you tried to change the registry in:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
```

If the operations there do not help, install the software:

[Easy Context Menu 1.6](https://www.sordum.org/7615/easy-context-menu-v1-6/)

Comment: Yup, sorry. beginner mistakes, my bad. I have updated the question. Thanks for the advice, really helpful and solved the problem. Easy Context Menu is really very useful and I really like it.